# How to get default volume on Mac OS X 64-bit?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, macos-carbon

What's the way to get default volume on Mac 64-bit?

I have a code like that:

```
    GetVolParmsInfoBuffer buf_64 = { 0 };  
 status = FSGetVolumeParms(vol_ref, // use default volume   
                     &buf_64, // write  
                  req_count);
```

The problem is that I can't pass 0 in vol_ref. On Mac 32-bit I could write:

```
    GetVolParmsInfoBuffer buf_32 = { 0 };  
 HParamBlockRec pb;  
 pb.ioParam.ioCompletion = NULL; // not doing async I/O  
 pb.ioParam.ioNamePtr = NULL; // we don't use path name  
 pb.ioParam.ioVRefNum = 0; // use default volume  
 pb.ioParam.ioBuffer = reinterpret_cast(&buf_32); // write data here  
 pb.ioParam.ioReqCount = req_count;   
 OSErr err = PBHGetVolParmsSync(&pb);  
 ASSERT_EQ(err, noErr);
```

Thanks in advance,
   - Oleksii

Comment: What do you mean by “default volume”? What are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

In the File Manager docs, you'll notice a function group titled [“Manipulating the Default Volume”](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000107-CH1g-TPXREF134). All of those functions are deprecated.

If you search Google for the functions therein, particularly `HSetVol`, you'll find [this mailing list post by Eric Schlegel](http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-development/2002/Dec/msg00111.html), which says `HSetVol` had the effect of setting the current working directory (expressed as a volume/directory pair) on Mac OS. He also says that it doesn't work on Mac OS X: It should work on File Manager functions, but does not set the working directory used for resolving relative paths in other APIs (e.g., `open` and `fopen`) like it did on Mac OS.

Moreover, those functions are not available in 64-bit Mac OS X. So the answer is: You don't, because there is no default volume.

The old meaning of it was analogous to the current working directory, so you can do the same thing by [getting the CWD](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getcwd.3.html) and [resolving that path to an FSRef](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSPathMakeRef). However, for a Mac OS X application (particularly one that doesn't set the CWD by any means, as most don't), this is not terribly useful: The default CWD for an application is /, the root directory of the boot volume. On the other hand, if you run your executable directly or under Xcode's Debugger, its CWD will not be /, which means it could be some other volume—most probably, the one with your Home folder on it.

You should refer to the boot volume (or whatever volume you're interested in) specifically, not attempt to get or simulate getting the default (current working) directory.

For the boot volume, you might try `kOnSystemDisk`, which is one of [the constants in the Folder Manager](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Folder_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Disk_and_Domain_Constants). If that doesn't work, use [Folder Manager's `FSFindFolder` function](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Folder_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSFindFolder) to retrieve the System folder, then use [File Manager's `FSGetVolumeInfo` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSGetCatalogInfo) to get what volume it's on.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I don't really know what "default volume" is. All I know is that Carbon manual (File Manager) says:

> ioVRefNum
>   A volume reference number, 0 for the default volume, or a drive number.

Well, I seem to find the answer for my question.

```
FSVolumeInfoParam vol_info = { 0 };
vol_info.ioVRefNum = kFSInvalidVolumeRefNum; // will obtain it
vol_info.volumeIndex = 1; // XXX: is it the default volume as well?
vol_info.whichInfo = kFSVolInfoNone; // don't pass volume info
err = PBGetVolumeInfoSync(&vol_info);
```

The only thing I'm not sure of is if the 1st volume is the default one...

P.S. I guess the problem is that I don't quite understand what "default volume" really is ;-)